# sorting a large list of doubles in descending order

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a rather large list consisting of several thousand doubles and I wish to sort it in descending order.

`xlist` is my list of doubles.

I tried

```
xlist.Sort();
xlist.Reverse();
```

and

```
xlist.OrderByDescending(d => d);
```

Then I proceed to use for loop to print out the contents of the list. Neither of these work. What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not assigning the sorted list to the variable. You probably want:

```
xlist = xlist.OrderByDescending(d => d).ToList();
```

**Example**:

```
IList<double> list = new List<double>() { 10, 22, 71.2, 12.4, 1.78, 90.1, 107.33, 5.9 };
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unsorted: " + string.Join(",", list)); 

list = list.OrderByDescending(d => d).ToList();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Reverse Sorted: " + string.Join(",", list));
```

**Output**:

```
Unsorted: 10,22,71.2,12.4,1.78,90.1,107.33,5.9
Sorted: 107.33,90.1,71.2,22,12.4,10,5.9,1.78
```

**Performance**: It took **0.41** seconds to sort **1,000,000** random double values (if you consider that to be a large list).

Comment: To be more exact: you did not read the documentation and overlooked that the RETURN is the ordered result - the original list is not changed. Ups.

Comment: When we say a `large list` the `Linq2Object` is not an option.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - whos we? the op said thousands not millions. linq should be fine up untill 100,000's then it will start to be annoying

Comment: @RadioSpace, we are we! What about scaleability?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what *Vlad* pointed out, if you want to sort the list in place, without creating a new list, try using [this overload of the `Sort` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
xlist.Sort((a, b) => Math.Sign(b - a));
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way is to use the `List.Sort` method with the following descending comparer as the argument:

```
xlist.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it like this:

```
var sortedList = from element in xlist
                 orderby element descending
                 select element;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a list using **OrderByDescending(d => d)** under System.Linq.
The function above will return a new list instance instead of sorting the list itself. So your final code should be:

`xlist = xlist.OrderByDescending(d => d).ToList();`

Now if your list contains a two dimensional array, you can sort the list by specifying the value needed in the array. for example:

```
double[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3};
double[] arr2 = {5, 6, 8};

List<double[]> Items = new List<double[]>();
Items.Add(arr1);
Items.Add(arr2);

Items = Items.OrderByDescending(d => d[2]).ToList();
```

The list will be sorted by the 2nd value of the array (6 and 2)